# Adding Multiple Recipients using Sendgrid marketing Email in PHP

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

Hi I am using Sendgrid marketing email API to send bulk of emails.Here i need to add multiple recipients in the list. I have seen lots of answers but i am not clear with any answer. This is the code I'm using to add single email to the list.

```
$data=array('email'=>'xxx@example.com',
'name'=>'XXXXX',
);
$email_add_data=array(
'api_user'=>$user,
'api_key'=>$password,
'list'=>$list_name,
'data'=>  json_encode($data)
);
```

In the above code, how can i change the data array, so that I can be able to add multiple email recipients address

Comment: You could just try RTFMing: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html  They even have an example showing what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You would pretty much need a `&data[]=` param for each recipient you need added to your list. That's why you'd have to loop through your data, like this:

```
$email = array('andreis@domain.com','andrei2@domain.com');
$name = array('andrei1','andrei2');
for($i=0;$i<count($email);$i++)
{
   $data[] = json_encode(array('email' => $email[$i],
               'name' => $name[$i]
                 ));    

}
$url = 'http://api.sendgrid.com/';

for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
$params = array(
          'api_user' => 'SENDGRID_USERNAME',
          'api_key' => 'SENDGRID_PASSWORD',
          'list' => 'Test list',
          'data' => $data[$i]
           );
$request =  $url.'api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json';
```